# Capybara and before(:all) in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, bdd

Here's my complete spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Idea page", js: true do

  subject { page }

  before(:all) do
    create(:idea)
    visit root_path
    click_link "Log In"
  end

  context "Single idea" do
    before do
      page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="accordion"]/div/div[1]/a').click
    end

    it { should have_selector('a',text:'Claim') }
    it "should have a button for reporting the idea"
    it "should have a button for opening all links"

    describe "Claiming" do
      before do
        click_link "Claim"
      end
      it {should have_selector('a', text:'Claimed')}
    end

  end
end
```

Without `(:all)` (i.e, when it's just `before` in the first block), the browser opens, clicks on the Login link, goes to the right page, and clicks on the link. Nice.

But then it does it all over again before it tries clicking the second link ("Claim"), which is both time-consuming and error-prone. So I tried to fix this with `before(:all)`.

But now, it just pops open Firefox, waits for a moment, and closes it again without doing anything. Test fails say:

```
Failures:

  1) Idea page Single idea 
     Failure/Error: page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="accordion"]/div/div[1]/a').click
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "//*[@id=\"accordion\"]/div/div[1]/a"
     # ./spec/features/ideas_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Idea page Single idea Claiming 
     Failure/Error: page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="accordion"]/div/div[1]/a').click
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "//*[@id=\"accordion\"]/div/div[1]/a"
     # ./spec/features/ideas_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Obviously, since the browser page was blank.

What am I missing? Thank you.

**Edit:** Maybe there's something basic I don't understand. With `before(:each)` here's what the test tries to do:

1) Log in to the webapp, make sure there's a 'Claim' button.

2) Log in to the webapp *again*, open the accordion *again*, and now click that 'Claim` button to see what's going to happen.

So the beginning of every step is exactly the same, the browser doing the same thing again and again. Is that how it's supposed to be?

If so, why do I get errors when I do this? Specifically, with `before(:each)` I get this:

```
Failures:

  1) Idea page Single idea Claiming 
     Failure/Error: it {should have_selector('a', text:'Claimed')}
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError:
       Modal dialog present
     # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130116-3734-lw7267/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10287:in `nsCommandProcessor.execute'
     # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130116-3734-lw7267/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7328:in `Dispatcher.executeAs/<'
     # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130116-3734-lw7267/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7488:in `Resource.handle'
     # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130116-3734-lw7267/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7435:in `Dispatcher.dispatch'
     # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130116-3734-lw7267/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:10119:in `WebDriverServer/<.handle'
     # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130116-3734-lw7267/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1935:in `unknown'
     # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130116-3734-lw7267/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:2261:in `ServerHandler.handleResponse'
     # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130116-3734-lw7267/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1168:in `Connection.process'
     # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130116-3734-lw7267/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1616:in `RequestReader._handleResponse'
     # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130116-3734-lw7267/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1464:in `RequestReader._processBody'
     # [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130116-3734-lw7267/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1333:in `RequestReader.onInputStreamReady'
     # ./spec/features/ideas_spec.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Even though I see the browser clicking the button, turning it to "Claimed", and there is no modal dialog shown.

**Edit 2:** I stand corrected! There **was** a modal dialog there after all! I fixed the JS to stop showing it, and the test now passes. I still think it's weird that the framework has to repeat the whole sequence from scratch every step (seems like a waste of work), but whatever. Thank you!

Comment: If you use a [shared_context](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) you can put the login process in that, and makes it clearer what you're doing `include_context "After signing in"`… and it cuts down on typing!

Comment: @iain comes to the rescue yet again! :) Thank you! Will definitely check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the test data, including the capybara session data (such as logged-in state) and the model created by `create(:idea)` are wiped out between specs.

You want to go with `before(:each)` not `:all`, even though it is more time consuming.

Comment: Some clarification, when @ezuk had just `before`, that was doing a `before(:each)`. They are equivalent.

Comment: No, `before(:each)` is already the default, and that's exactly what I don't want. I've read the docs before asking. :)

Comment: if you run a `before(:all)` and do a `create(:idea)` that model will be destroyed between your specs. Capybara will destroy its session data, etc. You very much do not want `before(:all)`

Comment: In other words, to use `before(:all)` you have to maintain state between tests, and each testing framework is going to fight you every step of the way in order to do that.

Comment: Thanks @DanielEvans; So I think I'm trying to solve the wrong thing. Edited the question to explain why I was trying to avoid `before(:each)` and what happens when I use it.