# "background(:all)" block doesn't work in rpsec feature spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec

I'm using rspec, capybara and Selenium to test my whole application stack. I've turned off transactional fixtures, and I'm using database cleaner to clean my database only after the whole suite has been run. These allows me to test things based using objects created in preceding tests.

Anyway, let's say I want to create user a999 (via a form, so a test in itself) and then proceed to test logging him out and logging him back in.

```
def sign_up(first_name, last_name, profile_name, email, password)
    visit "/"
    click_link "Register"
    fill_in('First name', with: first_name)
    fill_in('Last name', with: last_name)            
    fill_in('Profile name', with: profile_name)
    fill_in('Email', with: email)
    fill_in('Password', with: password)
    fill_in('Password confirmation', with: password)
    click_button 'Sign up'
end

feature "user a999 sign up", js: true do
    before(:each){
       sign_up( @a999.first_name, @a999.last_name, @a999.profile_name, @a999.email, @a999.password )
    }

    scenario "welcome message" do
        expect(page).to have_content ("Welcome," + @a999.first_name)
    end

    scenario "can log out" do          
    end

    scenario "can log in" do
    end
end
```

The code above almost works. This is what happens when it's run:

The before block signs up the user before the "welcome message" expectation (I see it physically happening in Firefox thanks to Selenium), and then the welcome message appears after a redirect so the "welcome message" spec passes.

However, because I have the before block set to 'each' the before block is run another two times, meaning I now have three a999 users in the database.

Of course, and setting the before block to (:all) should fix this problem. The user is signed up one, and we go from there, signing the **exact same** user in and out. It's a feature test that tests the whole stack remember, so I want to do this properly, emulate how a real user will be using my app.

```
def sign_up(first_name, last_name, profile_name, email, password)
    visit "/"
    click_link "Register"
    fill_in('First name', with: first_name)
    fill_in('Last name', with: last_name)            
    fill_in('Profile name', with: profile_name)
    fill_in('Email', with: email)
    fill_in('Password', with: password)
    fill_in('Password confirmation', with: password)
    click_button 'Sign up'
end

feature "user a999 sign up", js: true do
    before(:all){
       sign_up( @a999.first_name, @a999.last_name, @a999.profile_name, @a999.email, @a999.password )
    }

    scenario "welcome message" do
        expect(page).to have_content ("Welcome," + @a999.first_name)
    end

    scenario "can log out" do          
    end

    scenario "can log in" do
    end
end
```

But with this code **nothing** happens at all. Seriously, just nothing. Selenium doesn't follow the code in the before block at all! **Firefox doesn't even start up.**

Why is this? I mean, that should work at the very least.

before(:each) = signs user up before my eyes

before(:all) = completely dead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why nothing comes up at all, but based on numerous posts*, you can't reasonable use `before(:all)` with capybara, since it resets the session between each example.

*Related posts:

- [Capybara and before(:all) in rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364879/capybara-and-beforeall-in-rspec)
- [capybara/selenium with rspec before :all hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630170/capybara-selenium-with-rspec-before-all-hook)

Comment: Hmm okay. Makes sense, means every single expectation will work independently of each other, but it seems really wasteful at the same time!

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry about that, I'll have a look through my questions.

Comment: @Starkers - That's great. I think you'll spread a lot of good will. :-) BTW, I deleted my comments.